# Artifactory. How to disable access via native browser

Tags: artifactory

I use Artifactory аs a private repository. I take link on my repository to use it to gradle. However, if you enter this link in the browser, you will be able to download the jar file from the browser. How can I disable this functionality?

Comment: Why don't you just enable security in Artifactory to disallow anonymous access?

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory does not have built in functionality for disabling the Web UI.
Depending on your use case you can block access to the UI by limiting access to the Web UI using an HTTP proxy in front of Artifactory (or an organizational proxy, firewall etc).
For example, you can limit the access to the web UI only to certain IP address or address ranges.
If you want to completely block web browsers from accessing Artifactory you can configure the reverse proxy to block certain user agents.

Answer (score -1):

CloudRepo provides private and public repositories, if you'd like to prevent anyone from using your stuff you can toggle that repository to private.